# ModalViewController fires too late

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I'm opening a ModelViewController that loads updates through XML

In ViewController.m

```
LoadUpdatesView *luv = [[LoadUpdatesView alloc]  initWithNibName:@"LoadUpdatesView" bundle:nil];
luv.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:luv animated:YES];
```

In LoadUpdatesView.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [self xmlloadUpdates];
}
```

xmlloadUpdates

```
- (void) xmlloadUpdates {

   statusmessage.text = @"Start loading Updates"; 
    NSString * path = @"xxx.xml";
    [self parseXMLFileAtURL:path];

    for(int iX = 0; iX < [stories count]; iX++) {   
        statusmessage.text = @"Loading %@ of %@ entries",iX,[stories count];
    }

}
```

However the modal window only shows after xmlloadUpdates has finished loading the updates through xml. However I want to display display the modal window first and then start doing the XML stuff (xmlloadupdates show status messages on the modal window)

Answer (score 1):

try with threads. Read about Concurrency Programming Guide: Dispatch Queues, here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html

Comment: I tried with  `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(xmlloadUpdates) withObject:nil];` however (because the xmlloadUpdates runs in the background?) i loose the ability to display status messages, like `statusmessage.text = @"Start loading Updates";`

Comment: create new queue with `dispatch_queue_t` and call your label update with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue,  ^{//somecode });` and `xmlLoadUpdate` call in `dispatch_async (yourNewQueue, ^{//xmlloadupdate});`. That will be ok.